# Problems with navigation on webshop

Tags: html, css, navigation

I have a bit of a problem i've been stuck on for 2-3 hours now. I'm working on a design in Tictail (e-commerce site) and i want to have a Facebook and Instagram logo in the navigation. As you can see on the picture below, the logos refuses to get in line with the text in the navigation. I can either have the logos over or under the text and this is driving me crazy. [I just drew the line to show what i mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lwCf.png)

```
    <nav id="main_navigation">
        <ul class="row">
            {{! Highlight "All items" if we are on a list page and no navigation item is selected }}
            <li class="column {{#list_page}}{{#no_current_navigation}}selected{{/no_current_navigation}}{{/list_page}}">
                <a href="{{store_url}}/products">
                    {{#lang}}Startsida{{/lang}}
                </a>
            </li>

            {{#navigation}}
            <li class="column {{#is_current}}selected{{/is_current}}">
                <a href="{{url}}">
                    {{label}}
                </a>
            </li>
            {{/navigation}}

            {{#store_blog_url}}
            <li class="column">
                <a href="{{store_blog_url}}" target="_blank">
                    {{#lang}}Blog{{/lang}}
                </a>
            </li>
            {{/store_blog_url}}
            <li class="column {{#about_page}}selected{{/about_page}}">
                <a href="{{store_url}}/page/about">
                    {{#lang}}Kundtjänst{{/lang}}
                </a>
            <li class="column {{#about_page}}selected{{/about_page}}">
                <a href="{{store_url}}/page/about">
                    {{#lang}}Om oss{{/lang}}
                </a>
            </li>
           <img src="http://i.imgur.com/JvXEXcC.png" alt="{{store_name}}" height="25" width="25" align="right"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/uUiJzIo.png" alt="{{store_name}}" height="25" width="25" align="right">
        </ul>
        {{! By using #is_current within a #navigation block we can find the currently selected navigation item }}
        {{#navigation}}
        {{#is_current}}
        {{! Render the submenu if it has any navigation items }}
        {{#children?}}
        <ul class="child_navigation row">
            {{#children}}
            <li class="column">
                <a href="{{url}}">
                    {{label}}
                </a>
            </li>
            {{/children}}
        </ul>
        {{/children?}}
        {{/is_current}}
        {{/navigation}}
```

This is how the navigation code looks like - in other words, here i have done nothing besides adding the pictures and made an "align="right".

```
/* ******************************

NAVIGATION

****************************** */

#main_navigation ul {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #8f8f8f;
    text-align: left;
    letter-spacing: 2px
}

#main_navigation li {
    margin: 0 0px;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 35px;
    font-weight: ;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-left: -15px;
}

#main_navigation a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px;
    color: #000;

    margin-right: 25px;

}
#main_navigation .selected a {
    color: #D0D1D0;
}

#main_navigation .child_navigation a {
    color: #908f94;
}
#main_navigation a:hover { 
color: #D0D1D0;>
```

This is how the CSS looks for the navigation.

I hope someone can help me, i don't know if i'm a bit diffuse, if so please let me know and i will try and explain better.

Comment: The top of you html is chopped off and I cannot see it.

Comment: can u give the elements a padding-top to align it vertical aligned? If not: please provide us a JSFiddle. We're always lazy here :)

Comment: I forgot to mention that i'm a newbie on this kind of stuff :) I edited the question now and added the full navigation code, but i don't know if that matters? Sorry, but what is a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

There is only one hyperlink in each li so:

```
#main_navigation a {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

may as well just be:

```
#main_navigation a {
    display: block;
}
```

the li should line up:

```
#main_navigation li {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Place your  each into an li

Change this:

```
    </li>
   <img src="http://i.imgur.com/JvXEXcC.png" alt="{{store_name}}" 

height="25" width="25" align="right"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/uUiJzIo.png" alt="{{store_name}}" height="25" width="25" align="right">
    </ul>
```

to this:

```
</li>
   <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/JvXEXcC.png" alt="{{store_name}}" height="25" width="25" align="right"></li>

   <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/uUiJzIo.png" alt="{{store_name}}" height="25" width="25" align="right"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This didn't work, Carol, see the picture i posted. Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

a few things i did here:

- Make an unordered list and inline the list items
- Make the line height equal the icon height, then the text centers automatically with the icons
- remove excess padding from the text link so it doesn't take up any more room (see the line height point above)

```css
/* ******************************

NAVIGATION

****************************** */

#main_navigation ul {
    list-style: none;
}

#main_navigation li {
    margin: 0 0px;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-weight: ;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    float: left;
    display: inilne-block;
}

#main_navigation li img {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  }

#main_navigation a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;

}
#main_navigation .selected a {
    color: #D0D1D0;
}

#main_navigation .child_navigation a {
    color: #908f94;
}
#main_navigation a:hover { 
color: #D0D1D0;
}
```

```html
<div id ="main_navigation">
<ul>
            <li class="column {{#about_page}}selected{{/about_page}}">
                <a href="{{store_url}}/page/about">
                    {{#lang}}Om oss{{/lang}}
                </a>
            </li>
  <li>
           <img src="http://i.imgur.com/JvXEXcC.png" alt="{{store_name}}">
    </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/uUiJzIo.png" alt="{{store_name}}">
    </li>
        </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please check the pictures i added. They lined up, but somehow everything got screwed up.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: Do you see the picture i posted? Everything collapsed on the website. The content on the front page got beside the navigation and the navigation became screwed up

Comment: Ah ok. Don't just copy and paste the code I posted, but instead use the concepts I provided you to fix your problem. Since I don't have all your code it's up to you to integrate my answer to your solution files. Do you understand the concepts I mentioned in my answer?

Comment: I understand the second point, but the rest could might as well be chinese for me. "Make an unordered list and inline the list items" - do you mean for all the options in the navigation?

Comment: Yes, any items you want to both put inline, and have on the same vertical center axis, put in the same unordered list that has it's list items set to inline-block and float left. Hopefully that's clear?

Comment: I actually got it to work now, they lined up. I used "#main_navigation li img" and played with the margin and padding. But when i made the images links, i couldn't handle them. Now it's impossible to get the images beside eachother, it's a big gap and i can't place them to the right edge. Do you know any solution?

Comment: Yes, use the solution I gave you.

Answer (score 0):

[This is what Nathaniel, they lined up, but the whole website got screwed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0ZTV.png)

[This is what happened Carol, it didn't work :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Bxo1.png)

Comment: you need to set a width or min-width on the list items

Comment: How do i do that? I acutally got it to work by working with the CSS, but when i made the images links they screwed up.